# How to get with Curses the window-size from a resized window?

Tags: perl, size, curses, window-resize

I tried it this way, but it doesn't work - the returned values from `getmaxyx` remain always the same.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use 5.012;
use Curses;

my $size_changed = 0;
$SIG{'WINCH'} = sub { $size_changed= 1; };

initscr(); 

my ( $row, $col );
getmaxyx( $row, $col );
addstr( "begin: $row - $col\n" );
refresh();

for ( 0 .. 19 ) {
    addstr( "-------------\n" );
    if ( $size_changed ) {
        getmaxyx( $row, $col );
        addstr( "new: $row - $col\n" );
        $size_changed = 0;
    }
    refresh();
    sleep 1;

}

sleep 3;
endwin();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use 5.012;
use Curses;

my $size_changed = 0;
$SIG{'WINCH'} = sub { $size_changed= 1; };

initscr(); 

my ( $row, $col );
getmaxyx( $row, $col );
addstr( "begin: $row - $col\n" );
refresh();

for ( 0 .. 19 ) {
    sleep 2;
    if ( $size_changed ) {
        endwin();
        refresh(); 
        getmaxyx( $row, $col );
        addstr( "new: $row - $col\n" );
        $size_changed = 0;
    }
}

sleep 3;
endwin();
```

^^^ this worked for me. according to [Writing Programs with NCURSES / Using NCURSES under XTERM](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses-intro.html#xterm) you are suppose to do "endwin() followed by an refresh()"

Answer (score 1):

Knowing almost nothing about `Curses`, at a first guess I'd say your problem is that you broke `$SIG{WINCH}`, because `libcurses` is going to want to use that to detect when the window may have changed size.

Comment: As a workaround instead of using `$SIG{WINCH}` I compare each time in a loop the old max_rows/max_cols with the new max_rows/max_cols.

Comment: Also see [`Signals::XSIG`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Signals::XSIG) for a way that you and `Curses` can share the `SIGWINCH` handler.

Comment: The standard way to detect a resize event is to watch for a virtual `KEY_RESIZE` event from `getch`.  But you're not reading any keystrokes.

Comment: @mob: I used `Signals::XSIG` in the first place. I retried it on this example, but I don't see it working.

Comment: @cjm: In the original code I'm reading keystrokes in a loop and `KEY_RESIZE` works fine.