# How to print or align menu at the middle of screen using perl

Tags: bash, perl, awk, ksh

I want to align this menu at the middle of screen using perl and also want to get  input at center of screen .
    Menu code  as follow

```
while(1){ // 
        printf "Please select from one of expense catagories";
        printf "1 - House \n";
        printf "2 - Grocery \n";
        printf "3 - Car \n";
        printf "4 - Hospital \n";
        printf "5 - Others \n";
        printf "q - quit \n";
        my $input = <STDIN>;
        if ($input =~ /q/) {
        exit;
        }//
```

I tried using tabs but when I resize screen its not properly aligned . So want to know the way to print at particular location on screen .

Currently output is as follow :

```
Please select from one of expense catagories
1 - House
2 - Grocery
3 - Car
4 - Hospital
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using the Curses::UI package, and (if you are using ncurses underneath), handle the resulting KEY_RESIZE inputs.

A similar question was asked in *[How to get with Curses the window-size from a resized window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769723/how-to-get-with-curses-the-window-size-from-a-resized-window)*, where the accepted answer seems to agree with that.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting number of columns in current terminal using `stty -a` command and use that value to determine position of the menu. (We can use printf to do left/right padding).

Before you print menu, determine the screen width using `stty -a` command everytime so that menu can be aligned accordingly.